# Craigslist API - how to post with RSS data?

Tags: api, forms, http-post

http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface - it says, "New postings are submitted to craigslist in RSS format with additional craigslist-specific elements via HTTPS POST"

How do I post a form passing rss data?

I was hoping to just have something like this:

```
<form action="https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post" type="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="area" value="richmond" />
  <input type="hidden" name="category" value="free" />
  <input type="hidden" name="reply-email" value="x@y.com" />
</form>
```

But, it says I have to supply the data in RSS format.

So is it something like this?

```
<form action="https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post" type="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="{all the RSS data goes here??}" />
</form>
```

Any help is super appreciated.  Eventually I'd like to build an android app that posts to Criagslist, but, just want to get a simple html form to test for proof of concept for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out, too, but from what I have read about this RSS interface it is only available for non-free categories like employment and real estate postings.  Those categories require you to purchase blocks of posting credits.

IMO this is a good reason not to use Craigs List.  If anything, they should open up the RSS interface to all categories and perhaps limit the rate of posting for free ads and/or let people buy blocks for other categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
The format of the request will look like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:cl="http://www.craigslist.org/about/cl-bulk-ns/1.0">
   <channel>
      <items>
         <rdf:li rdf:resource="NYCBrokerHousingSample1" />
      </items>
      <cl:auth username="Vusername@gmail.com" password="password" accountID="14" />
   </channel>
   <item rdf:about="NYCBrokerHousingSample1">
      <cl:category>fee</cl:category>
      <cl:area>nyc</cl:area>
      <cl:subarea>mnh</cl:subarea>
      <cl:neighborhood>Upper West Side</cl:neighborhood>
      <cl:housingInfo price="1450" bedrooms="0" sqft="600" />
      <cl:replyEmail privacy="C">bulkuser@bulkposterz.net</cl:replyEmail>
      <cl:brokerInfo companyName="Joe Sample and Associates" feeDisclosure="fee disclosure here" />
      <title>Spacious Sunny Studio in Upper West Side</title>
      <description><![CDATA[posting body here]]></description>
   </item>
   <item rdf:about="NYCBrokerHousingSample2">
      <cl:category>fee</cl:category>
      <cl:area>nyc</cl:area>
      <cl:subarea>mnh</cl:subarea>
      <cl:neighborhood>Chelsea</cl:neighborhood>
      <cl:housingInfo price="2175" bedrooms="1" sqft="850" catsOK="1" />
      <cl:mapLocation city="New York" state="NY" crossStreet1="23rd Street" crossStreet2="9th Avenue" latitude="40.746492" longitude="-74.001326" />
      <cl:replyEmail privacy="C" otherContactInfo="212.555.1212">bulkuser@bulkposterz.net</cl:replyEmail>
      <cl:brokerInfo companyName="Joe Sample and Associates" feeDisclosure="fee disclosure here" />
      <title>1BR Charmer in Chelsea</title>
      <description><![CDATA[posting body goes here]]></description>
      <cl:PONumber>Purchase Order 094122</cl:PONumber>
      <cl:image position="1">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QCARXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUA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`enter code here`P//Z</cl:image>
   </item>
</rdf:RDF>
```